# jquery ajax : what is the actual request sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the actual url sent to the server when I use the jquery ajax? And how do I access that value? For example, consider the following code:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "response.php",
data: {name:'Smith',age:10},
success: function(data) {
    ...
}
beforeSend: function(){
    console.log(url); 
    // what do I put here to see what is being sent
    // I am expecting to see "response.php?name=Smith&age=10"
}
...
```

So essentially what variable holds "response.php?name=Smith&age=10".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings object is fully populated when beforeSend is called:

```
beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
   console.log(settings.url);
   console.log(settings.data);  
}
```

$.ajax({ type: "POST", ... }) will log

```
response.php
name=Smith&age=10
```

and type: "GET"

```
response.php?name=Smith&age=10
undefined
```

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for.    @spender: the network panel helped a lot too.

Answer (score 2):

No variable holds

```
response.php?name=Smith&age=10
```

because you aren't sending the data as a query string. This would happen if you issued a GET request, but doesn't with a POST request.

You're sending the data in the *request body* of an HTTP post. The data is the data that you assigned to the `data` parameter. You don't need to round-trip it through jQuery's ajax methods. You've got it already. It's:

```
{name:'Smith',age:10}
```

does jQuery's interpretation of your data really matter?

Comment: so what would the answer be it if was a GET request?

Comment: I don't know. See my last sentence

Comment: @user3259040 What are you **actually** trying to do? It might give some insight as to why you think you need this data.

Comment: I wanted to see what exactly it was sending so that I could debug. The actual data is more complex and I wanted to see if it was valid.

Comment: Firebug/Developer tools/whatever your browser offers will allow you to look at this data in the network panel (or whatever its called). If you're on a Windows box, consider Fiddler.